Two different tables with the same col-spans
I'm trying to align the columns of two different tables that carry the same model of information, but not the same items.
This leads to columns of both tables being of different sizes, which makes absolute sense as some items in Table A may be larger than the ones in Table B.
My goal is to fight this and force both tables to have the exact same column sizes.
I also require not to set static widths, the tables should keep their automatic col sizing, they just should be applied equaly to both tables.
Here are my two main ideas that I consider sub-optimal (as they both require me to add complexity to either Table A, Table B or both):
1- Inject Table B <td>s into Table A and add a styled <td> (taking all col-spans) as a separator (I don't like this idea as it forces me to complexify Table A that is used in many other usecases).
2- Inject all of Table A data into Table B and hide it so that it is not displayed, but has an effect on the col widths (I don't like this idea because it forces a hidden rendering of potentially hundreds of elements).
Ideally I'd like to add the minimum level of complexity to Table B and none to Table A so that it stays a simple little component for later use, especially when not coupled to another table.
The two tables
I thank you for your time !

For complete flexibility the only thing I can think of is to render both tables, use JS to find their column widths and then decide what the best compromise for widths is for the two tables and then render them again (this time with opacity 1!) with the chosen widths.

You can check with below example:
   <style>
   table td:nth-child(1) { width: 20%;background-color: aqua;}
   table td:nth-child(2) { width: 10%; background-color: burlywood;}
   table td:nth-child(3) { width: 70%; background-color: chocolate;}
   </style>

   <table style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px auto;">
   <tr>
   <td>Col 1 Table 1</td>
   <td>Col 2 Table 1</td>
   <td>Col 3 Table 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Col 1 Table 1</td>
   <td>Col 2 Table 1 Col 2 Table 1 Col 2 Table 1</td>
   <td>Col 3 Table 1</td>
   </tr>

   </table>

   <table style="width: 100%; border:1px solid black; margin: 10px auto;">
   <tr>
   <td>Col 1 Table 2</td>
   <td>Col 2 Table 2</td>
   <td>Col 3 Table 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Col 1 Table 1</td>
   <td>Col 2 Table 1 Col 2 Table 1 Col 2 Table 1 Col 2 Table 1</td>
   <td>Col 3 Table 1</td>
   </tr>

   </table>

And if you have long word issue you can follow:
Break long word in table cell with percentage widths
Regards
Shawpnendu
Coderstechzone

Where did those %s come from???
